# IIS Express No AppSettings

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-express

I am running a .NET 4.0 Web Application. Under IIS Express ( and only IIS Express ) none of my APPSettings are read into the AppSettings collection. When I look into this collection it is empty even though I have about 15 app settings in the web.config. Any sugguestions on what is going on?

This is a Web Application project. I am using web.config transformations but I believe those only are used when publishing.

Comment: Check to see if its under the correct node. Make sure its in the <configuration> node. And not one of its child nodes or outside of it

Comment: How do you read into the AppSettings collection?

Comment: var configurationAppSettings = new AppSettingsReader();
                returnMe = ((int)(configurationAppSettings.GetValue(parameterName, typeof(int))));

as an example. Though I have used ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"] and it was empty as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing I've discovered that can cause appsettings not to load this is having a virtual directory nested in another directory

```
http://localhost:8181/xproject/mysite
```

changing it to

```
http://localhost:8181/xproject_mysite
```

fixed it for me.

I have no idea why though.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the the appSettings element in the web.config is a child element of the configuration element.

Comment: It is: <configuration>
  <appSettings>

Comment: As an example here is a sub copy:

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="version" value="2.0.0310.2011"/>
  </appSettings>